# Shared Memory Array of Strings with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ctypes

I'm trying to multiprocess some existing code and I'm finding that the pickling/unpickling of data to the processes is too slow with a `Pool`.  I think for my situation a `Manager` will suffer the same issues since it does the same pickling behind the scenes.

To solve the issue I'm trying to move to a shared memory array.  For this to work, I need an array of strings.  It seems that `multiprocessing.Array` supports a `ctypes.c_char_p` but I'm having difficulty extending this into an array of strings.  Below is a few of the many things I've tried.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ctypes
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.sharedctypes as mpsc
import numpy

# Tested possible solutions
ver = 1
if 1==ver:
    strings = mpsc.RawArray(ctypes.c_char_p, (' '*10, ' '*10, ' '*10, ' '*10))
elif 2==ver:
    tmp_strings = [mpsc.RawValue(ctypes.c_char_p, ' '*10) for i in xrange(4)]
    strings = mpsc.RawArray(ctypes.c_char_p, tmp_strings)
elif 3==ver:
    strings = []
    for i in xrange(4):
        strings.append( mpsc.RawValue(ctypes.c_char_p, 10) )

def worker(args):
    snum, lenarg = args
    string = '%s' % snum
    string *= lenarg
    strings[snum] = string
    return string

# Main progam
data = [(i, numpy.random.randint(1,10)) for i in xrange(3)]
print 'Testing version ', ver
print
print 'Single process'
for x in map(worker, data):
    print '%10s : %s' % (x, list(strings))
print

print 'Multi-process'
pool = mp.Pool(3)
for x in pool.map(worker, data):
    print '%10s : %s' % (x, list(strings))
    print '            ', [isinstance(s, str) for s in strings]
```

Note that I'm using the `multiprocessing.sharedctypes` because I don't need locking and it should be fairly interchangeable with `multiprocessing.Array`

The issue with the above code is that the resultant `strings` object contains regular strings, not shared memory strings coming out of the `mpsc.RawArray` constructor.  With version 1 and 2 you can see how the data gets scrambled when working out of process (as expected).  For me, version 3 looked like it worked initially but you can see the `=` is just setting the object to a regular string and while this works for the short test, in the larger program it creates issues.

It seems like there should be a way to create a shared array of pointers where the pointers point strings in shared memory space. The `c_void_p` type complains if you try to initialize it with a `c_str_p` type and I haven't had any luck manipulating the underlying address pointers directly yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your third solution doesn't work as `strings` isn't changed by multiprocessing part but has been modified by single process part. You can have a check by commenting your single process part.

Second, This one will work:

```
import ctypes
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.sharedctypes as mpsc
import numpy

strings = [mpsc.RawArray(ctypes.c_char, 10) for _ in xrange(4)]

def worker(args):
    snum, lenarg = args
    string = '%s' % snum
    string *= lenarg
    strings[snum].value = string
    return string

# Main progam
data = [(i, numpy.random.randint(1,10)) for i in xrange(4)]

print 'Multi-process'
print "Before: %s" % [item.value for item in strings]
pool = mp.Pool(4)
pool.map(worker, data)
print 'After : %s' % [item.value for item in strings]
```

output:

```
Multi-process
Before: ['', '', '', '']
After : ['0000000', '111111', '222', '3333']
```

Comment: Thanks.  Should have caught that myself.  Definitely runs faster than pickling the data.